# Creating a cut on an object with circular outer edges

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry, bisect

Please refer to the images. I extruded these edges along normals, then made it so that the new faces intersected with parts of the same object. I would like to create a cut where the intersection is

[image: question image 3]
I have read through the similar questions but mine seems different from theirs because

1. the cut angle needs to be consistent on either side, and I can't actually get a perfectly perpendicular view in order to Bisect it
2. the extruded faces do not form a flat plane, but has a slight curvature as is required to keep the outer edges circular. A flat plane cannot in fact create this cut

---

I tried just using Bisect, eyeballing from the side trying to get a good angle

[image: question image]
the result:
[image: Bisect result]

Please help

Comment: Hello, it's a bit hard to understand, maybe show a picture of the object you are trying to achieve?